# How to get row data using angular material?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material2

I have angular4 with materialize table Api so I am trying to get row data when user click on the row but its not passing data, How can i pass data to component from view any help will be appreciated ?

app.component.html

```
<div class="table-container">
<mat-table>
       <ng-container matColumnDef="eventType">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Event Type </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.eventType}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <!--<button (click)="newMessage()" class="button">New Message</button>-->
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="highlight(row._id,$event)"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
      </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
highlight(id,event){
        console.log('Event',event);
    }
```

Comment: It clearly seems to be working for me, please check [stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuvm31?file=app/table-filtering-example.html) here

Answer (score 2):

Change to following in your template `app.component.html`

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="highlight(row,$event)"></mat-row>
```

and you should write your click handler in your component `app.component.ts`

```
highlight(row,evt) :void{
   //console.log(row,evt);
}
```

Remove ._id from (click)="highlight(row._id,$event)" from your code.[refer this](https://angular-nuvm31-xehjxt.stackblitz.io)

Comment: error `__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'row-id' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
1`